# How can I import pymnet library?

Tags: pymnet

I am new to python. I am trying to use 'pymnet' library for multilayer network analysis. Somehow I could work with this library, but later, when I try to import the library I fount the following error.

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/61/5__nt2nn7ll4g4mwwckv8dk00000gn/T/ipykernel_2510/2101304131.py in 
1 import networkx
----> 2 from pymnet.net import MultilayerNetwork

/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymnet/**init**.py in 
22     pass
23
---> 24 from . import sampling
25

ImportError: cannot import name 'sampling' from partially initialized module 'pymnet' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymnet/**init**.py)

I use following configuration:

1. Conda environment
2. MacOS (m1)
3. python 3.9.7

I am looking forward to having solution from this big community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same issue and worked around it by adding `"pymnet.sampling"` pymnet setup.py file. So the packages line became:

```
packages=["pymnet", "pymnet.tests","pymnet.sampling","pymnet.visuals","pymnet.visuals.drawbackends","pymnet.isomorphisms","pymnet.graphlets"]
```

Then in my conda environment I reran `python setup.py install` and it it was able to import successfully.